# How can we get paypal billing AgreementId in IPN code

Tags: php, paypal

I was creating a paypal billing agreement using API php.
It works good, Is there any way we can get the Billing Agreement Id in Ipn.
I know we will get it in encrypted from. https://prnt.sc/r4hc2h Any one know how to decrypt it  ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no decrypted Billing Agreement ID to be had.

The value of `mp_id` is the only BA ID you will ever see or need. Store it and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Although the documentation says that it's encrypted or whatsoever, the `mp_id` in IPN message is what you need to charge a billing agreement.